# out of memory error in file manager

Tags: android, listview, out-of-memory

I made a custom file manager, and it is working fine. but it is loading and scrolling very slowly and suddenly there was outofmemory error. I am adding images on the side of the text view

```
package com.example.fileexplorer;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FileExplorer extends Activity {
    EditText et;
    ListView lv;
    ArrayList<Data> list;
    ArrayAdapter<Data> aa;
    LayoutInflater li;
    Context cv=this;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_file_explorer);
        et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_main);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_main);
        list = new ArrayList<Data>();

        readFiles();

        li=(LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        aa=new ArrayAdapter<Data>(cv,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list)
                {
                @Override
                public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Data d=list.get(position);

                View v=li.inflate(R.layout.list_inflate, null);

                ImageView iv=(ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.iv_inflate);
                TextView tv=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_inflate);
                Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), d.id);
                icon = getdecodedimage(icon, 50, 50);
                iv.setImageBitmap(icon);
                tv.setText(d.f_name);
                tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

                    return v;
                }

                };
                lv.setAdapter(aa);
    }

    private void readFiles()
    {
        File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
        File[] list_files = f.listFiles();
        Data d;
        for (int i = 0; i < list_files.length; i++) {
            d = new Data();
            if (list_files[i].isDirectory()) {
                d.f_name = list_files[i].getName().toString();
                d.id = R.drawable.folder;

                list.add(d);
            }

            // Detecting file extentions and giving appropriate image to it
            else if (list_files[i].isFile()) {

                int temp = (list_files[i].getName().lastIndexOf(".")) + 1;
                String extention = list_files[i].getName().substring(temp);

                if (extention.equalsIgnoreCase("img") || extention.equalsIgnoreCase("jpg")
                        || extention.equalsIgnoreCase("png")) {
                    d.f_name = list_files[i].getName().toString();
                    d.id = R.drawable.images;
                }

                else if (extention.equalsIgnoreCase("mp3") || extention.equalsIgnoreCase("wav")) {
                    d.f_name = list_files[i].getName().toString();
                    d.id = R.drawable.music;
                } 

                else if (extention.equalsIgnoreCase("mp4") || extention.equalsIgnoreCase("3gp")) {
                    d.f_name = list_files[i].getName().toString();
                    d.id = R.drawable.video;
                } 

                else if (extention.equalsIgnoreCase("doc")) {
                    d.f_name = list_files[i].getName().toString();
                    d.id = R.drawable.docx;
                } 

                else if (extention.equalsIgnoreCase("pdf")) {
                    d.f_name = list_files[i].getName().toString();
                    d.id = R.drawable.pdf;
                } 



                else if (extention.equalsIgnoreCase("txt")) {
                    d.f_name = list_files[i].getName().toString();
                    d.id = R.drawable.txt;
                } 

                else if (extention.equalsIgnoreCase("apk")) {
                    d.f_name = list_files[i].getName().toString();
                    d.id = R.drawable.apk;
                } 



                else if (extention.equalsIgnoreCase("xlsx")) {
                    d.f_name = list_files[i].getName().toString();
                    d.id = R.drawable.exel;
                } 

                else if (extention.equalsIgnoreCase("pptx")) {
                    d.f_name = list_files[i].getName().toString();
                    d.id = R.drawable.pptx;
                }
                else
                {
                    d.f_name = list_files[i].getName().toString();
                    d.id = R.drawable.unknown;
                }

                list.add(d);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.file_explorer, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_home) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    class FileHandlingAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    }
    public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newWidth, int newHeight) {

        int width = bm.getWidth();
        int height = bm.getHeight();
        float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
        float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
        // CREATE A MATRIX FOR THE MANIPULATION
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        // RESIZE THE BIT MAP
        matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

        // "RECREATE" THE NEW BITMAP
        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);

        // Mayur must
        // watch.........................................................
        // bm.recycle();
        // .....................................................................

        return resizedBitmap;
    }
    public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            final int halfHeight = height / 2;
            final int halfWidth = width / 2;

            // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and
            // keeps both
            // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
            while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
                inSampleSize *= 2;
            }
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }
    Bitmap getdecodedimage(Bitmap bmp, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayBitmapStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 85, byteArrayBitmapStream);
        byte[] b = byteArrayBitmapStream.toByteArray();
        BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b, 0, b.length, options);

        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b, 0, b.length, options);

    }
}
```

[![this is the screenshot][1]][1]

The scroll is also very slow, how can I optimize it?

Comment: 1. why are you not caching decoded bitmaps? 2. what is the point of `getdecodedimage` if you are already have decoded bitmap which takes memory - it just creates new one?

Comment: how do i do it? can you give any  code for refence @Selvin

Comment: sure `if(containter.hasAlread(bitmapid)) bitmap = container.getBitmapById(bitmapid) else { bitmap = decodeBitmapfromId(bitmapid); container.put(bitmapid, bitmap) }`

Comment: what is a containter?

Comment: oh come on computer science basics: [Container](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Container_(abstract_data_type)) ... of course i meant some kind of associative container ...

Comment: what is a container? im sorry but never cahced bitmaps

Comment: it seems like you never cached anything ... it is a basic programming pattern, usually implemented on some kind of associative container (fx. map)

Comment: you mean any list or arraylist?

Comment: flying spaghetti monser save us ... i'm trolling you ... yes, you can implement it by yourself, of course it could incrase you low programming skills ... but there is implementation already ... http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/util/LruCache.html let Key be an Integer and value Bitmap ... heh ... i miss the times when programming was start learning by implementing maps, queues, searching, on simple arrays ... not by copy&pasting ... when every aspiring programmer known(and could implement) at least 3 search argorimts ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92853/discussion-between-parth-anjaria-and-selvin).

Comment: i am still a newbie and i dont copypaste, but i need to know atleast the basics. plaese help me @Selvin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use LruCache

This code is working

```
package com.example.fileexplorer;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.util.ArrayList;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.LruCache;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class FileExplorer extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {
    EditText et;
    ListView lv;
    ArrayList<Data> list;
    ArrayAdapter<Data> aa;
    LayoutInflater li;
    Context cv = this;
    String main_path = "/storage";
    File[] list_files;
    int exit_count = 0; // Double tap back key to exit
    ArrayList<Data>list_search;
    View v;

    private LruCache<Integer, Bitmap> mLrucatche;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_file_explorer);


        final int maxMemory=(int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()/1024);
        final int cacheSize=maxMemory/8;
        mLrucatche=new LruCache<Integer,Bitmap>(cacheSize){

            @Override
            protected int sizeOf(Integer key, Bitmap value) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return value.getByteCount()/1024;
            }
        };


        et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_main);
        et.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_main);
        list = new ArrayList<Data>();
        list_search=new ArrayList<Data>();
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);


        new FileHandlingAsync().execute(main_path);
        // readFiles(main_path);

        li = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        aa = new ArrayAdapter<Data>(cv, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list) {
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Data d = list.get(position);

                v = li.inflate(R.layout.list_inflate, null);

                ImageView iv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.iv_inflate);
                TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_inflate);

                Bitmap thumnailImage=null;

//              Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), d.id);
//              icon = getdecodedimage(icon, 50, 50);
//              iv.setImageBitmap(icon);

                // Making text short if more than 25 words...only for files
                if (d.f_name.length() > 25) {
                    if (!(list_files[position]).isDirectory()) {
                        d.f_name = d.f_name.substring(0, 22);
                        d.f_name = d.f_name + "...";
                    }
                }

                tv.setText(d.f_name);
                tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                //mayu
                int key=d.id;
                thumnailImage=getBitmapFromMcache(key);
                if(thumnailImage==null)
                {
                    BitmapWorkerTask task=new BitmapWorkerTask(iv);
                    task.execute(key);
                }
                iv.setImageBitmap(thumnailImage);
                return v;
            }

        };lv.setAdapter(aa);



        //Search feature
        et.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmapFromMcache(Integer id)
    {
        return mLrucatche.get(id);
    }

    public void addBitmapToMcache(Integer id,Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        if(getBitmapFromMcache(id)==null)
        {
            mLrucatche.put(id, bitmap);
        }
    }

    private void readFiles(String path) {
        File f = new File(path);
        list_files = f.listFiles();
        Data d;
        for (int i = 0; i < list_files.length; i++) {
            d = new Data();
            if (list_files[i].isDirectory()) {

                String name1=list_files[i].getName();
                name1=name1.substring(0, 1);

                //Removing directories which starts from "." or "$"
                if(name1.equals(".")||name1.equals("$"))
                {

                }else{
                d.f_name = list_files[i].getName().toString();
                d.id = R.drawable.folder;

                list.add(d);
                }
            }

            // Detecting file extentions and giving appropriate image to it
            else if (list_files[i].isFile()) {

                int temp = (list_files[i].getName().lastIndexOf(".")) + 1;
                String extention = list_files[i].getName().substring(temp);

                switch (extention) {
                case "img":
                case "jpg":
                case "jpeg":
                case "png": d.f_name = list_files[i].getName().toString();
                d.id = R.drawable.images;
                    break;

                    case "mp3":
                    case "wav":
                        d.f_name = list_files[i].getName().toString();
                        d.id = R.drawable.music;
                        break;
                    case "mp4":
                    case "3gp":
                        d.f_name = list_files[i].getName().toString();
                        d.id = R.drawable.video;
                        break;
                    case "doc":
                        d.f_name = list_files[i].getName().toString();
                        d.id = R.drawable.docx;
                        break;
                    case "pdf":
                        d.f_name = list_files[i].getName().toString();
                        d.id = R.drawable.pdf;
                        break;
                    case "txt":
                        d.f_name = list_files[i].getName().toString();
                        d.id = R.drawable.txt;
                        break;
                    case "apk":
                        d.f_name = list_files[i].getName().toString();
                        d.id = R.drawable.apk;
                        break;
                    case "xlsx":
                        d.f_name = list_files[i].getName().toString();
                        d.id = R.drawable.exel;
                        break;
                    case "pptx":
                        d.f_name = list_files[i].getName().toString();
                        d.id = R.drawable.pptx;
                        break;
                    case "zip":
                        d.f_name = list_files[i].getName().toString();
                        d.id = R.drawable.zip;
                        break;
                    case "rar":
                        d.f_name = list_files[i].getName().toString();
                        d.id = R.drawable.rar;
                        break;

                default:
                    d.f_name = list_files[i].getName().toString();
                    d.id = R.drawable.unknown;
                    break;
                }
                list.add(d);

            }
        }


    }

    //For search feature
    TextWatcher watcher=new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub



        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };


    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (list_files[position].isDirectory()) {
            Data d = list.get(position);
            String name = d.f_name;
            main_path = main_path + "/" + name;
            ArrayList<Data> temp_list = new ArrayList<Data>();
            temp_list.addAll(list);

            try {
                list.clear();
                new FileHandlingAsync().execute(main_path);
                // readFiles(main_path);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                list.addAll(temp_list);
                Toast.makeText(cv, "Cannot open", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(cv, "Not a directory", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.file_explorer, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_search) {

            et.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (!(exit_count == 1)) {
            if (!main_path.equals("/storage")) {
                int index = main_path.lastIndexOf("/");
                main_path = main_path.substring(0, index);
                list.clear();
                readFiles(main_path);
                aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                exit_count++;
                Toast.makeText(cv, "Tap again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            System.exit(0);
        }

    }

    class FileHandlingAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        ProgressDialog pd;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            pd = new ProgressDialog(cv);
            pd.setMessage("Getting list of files...");
            pd.setCancelable(false);
            pd.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String m_path = params[0];
            readFiles(m_path);

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
            pd.dismiss();
        }

    }

    public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newWidth, int newHeight) {

        int width = bm.getWidth();
        int height = bm.getHeight();
        float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
        float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
        // CREATE A MATRIX FOR THE MANIPULATION
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        // RESIZE THE BIT MAP
        matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

        // "RECREATE" THE NEW BITMAP
        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);

        // Mayur must
        // watch.........................................................
        // bm.recycle();
        // .....................................................................

        return resizedBitmap;
    }

    public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            final int halfHeight = height / 2;
            final int halfWidth = width / 2;

            // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and
            // keeps both
            // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
            while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
                inSampleSize *= 2;
            }
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }

    Bitmap getdecodedimage(Bitmap bmp, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayBitmapStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 85, byteArrayBitmapStream);
        byte[] b = byteArrayBitmapStream.toByteArray();
        BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b, 0, b.length, options);

        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b, 0, b.length, options);

    }

    class BitmapWorkerTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Bitmap>
    {
        private final WeakReference<ImageView> ivReference;

        public BitmapWorkerTask(ImageView imageview) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            ivReference=new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageview);
        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Integer... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(cv.getResources(),params[0]);
            addBitmapToMcache(Integer.valueOf(params[0]), bitmap);
            return bitmap;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(ivReference!=null || result!=null)
            {
                final ImageView imageview=(ImageView)ivReference.get();
                if(imageview!=null)
                {
                    imageview.setImageBitmap(result);
                }
            }

        }
    }

}
```

hope this helps u

Comment: If u want search feature in your app then use TextWatcher...otherwise comment it