# I implement search on actionbar for listview item but it search only one character

Tags: android, search

I implement search on Action bar for List view item but it search only one character
how to implement for all word?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, lpease have a read on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Show us what you tried!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this code :

```
TextWatcher watcher = new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            list.clear();

            String search = et.getText().toString();
            Log.d("Parth", "Search: "+search);
            int length = search.length();

            Data d = new Data();

            for (int i = 0; i < searchbackup.size(); i++) {
                d = searchbackup.get(i);
                if (d.f_name.length() >= length) {
                    if (search.equalsIgnoreCase(d.f_name.substring(0, length))) {
                        list.add(d);
                        Log.d("Parth", "test:"+d.f_name);
                    }
                }
            }

            aa.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };
```

try this,

I have done search for my file manager
[out of memory error in file manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33235201/out-of-memory-error-in-file-manager?noredirect=1#comment54274698_33235201)